# Types of metal or types of metals

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, singular

Which one of these examples is correct?

1. Types of **metal**
2. Types of **metals**

Do they have different meanings?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but **types of metals** is commonly used.
See the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=17&content=type%20of%20metals%2C%20types%20of%20metals&smoothing=3&year_end=2000&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctype%20of%20metals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20metals%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctype%20of%20metals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20metals%3B%2Cc0) to see both usages

Comment: Plural is more common for practically all permutations of ***types / kinds / sorts / varieties** of [NOUN]*, but to some extent it does depend on what *specific* [NOUN] is involved. For example, *There are many **varieties of fruit*** is just slightly more common than *...varieties of **fruits***. And with *There are many **forms of [NOUN]***, it's nearly always singular. There's probably no clear-cut reason for any variability, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would regard "types of metals" as wrong (Australian English). I believe it is also wrong in UK, but correct in US.

Comment: Your belief about UK usage is consistent with my experience as a UK resident.

Comment: You're correct that "types of metals" is not incorrect in the US. However, I would say that "types of metal" sounds much more colloquial to my ear, while "types of metals" sounds a more clinical or scientific.

Comment: Regarding technical uses, in my technical editing (American English, British English, and Australian English), I would check only that the author is consistent throughout the research article. Both usages are clear and unambiguous.